# Ajenti port busy. My server has a several web-sites. When I reset them, Ajenti not working

Tags: config

The Ajenti config json is:

```
{
    "users": {
        "root": {
            "configs": {
                "ajenti.plugins.notepad.notepad.Notepad": "{\"bookmarks\": [], \"root\": \"/\"}", 
                "ajenti.plugins.terminal.main.Terminals": "{\"shell\": \"sh -c $SHELL || bash\"}", 
                "ajenti.plugins.openvpn.backend.OpenVPNBackend": "{\"password\": \"\", \"addr\": \"\"}", 
                "ajenti.plugins.logs.main.Logs": "{\"root\": \"/var/log\"}", 
                "ajenti.plugins.dashboard.dash.Dash": "{\"widgets\": [{\"index\": 0, \"config\": null, \"container\": \"1\", \"class\": \"ajenti.plugins.sensors.memory.MemoryWidget\"}, {\"index\": 1, \"config\": null, \"container\": \"1\", \"class\": \"ajenti.plugins.sensors.memory.SwapWidget\"}, {\"index\": 2, \"config\": null, \"container\": \"1\", \"class\": \"ajenti.plugins.dashboard.welcome.WelcomeWidget\"}, {\"index\": 0, \"config\": null, \"container\": \"0\", \"class\": \"ajenti.plugins.sensors.uptime.UptimeWidget\"}, {\"index\": 1, \"config\": null, \"container\": \"0\", \"class\": \"ajenti.plugins.power.power.PowerWidget\"}, {\"index\": 2, \"config\": null, \"container\": \"0\", \"class\": \"ajenti.plugins.sensors.cpu.CPUWidget\"}]}", 
                "ajenti.plugins.mysql.api.MySQLDB": "{\"password\": \"741147\", \"user\": \"root\", \"hostname\": \"localhost\"}", 
                "ajenti.plugins.fm.fm.FileManager": "{\"start\": \"/\", \"root\": \"/\"}", 
                "ajenti.users.UserManager": "{\"sync-provider\": \"\"}", 
                "ajenti.plugins.tasks.manager.TaskManager": "{\"job_definitions\": [{\"schedule_hour\": \"8\", \"name\": \"toldot cache\", \"task_id\": \"e75e5903-be69-47a1-9464-1f383f5fe806\", \"schedule_special\": null, \"schedule_minute\": \"1\", \"schedule_day_of_month\": \"*\", \"id\": \"ef62cb19-cb0e-474a-ba39-265f59186a39\", \"schedule_month\": \"*\", \"schedule_day_of_week\": \"*\"}, {\"schedule_hour\": \"*\", \"name\": \"unnamed\", \"task_id\": \"cf23d1c8-c65e-41c0-8d25-e6f56513e8e7\", \"schedule_special\": null, \"schedule_minute\": \"0\", \"schedule_day_of_month\": \"*\", \"id\": \"b5518b37-ad77-415c-bd85-12c8237b2d2d\", \"schedule_month\": \"*\", \"schedule_day_of_week\": \"*\"}], \"task_definitions\": [{\"task_class\": \"ajenti.plugins.tasks.tasks.CommandTask\", \"params\": {\"command\": \"service rc.digitalocean start\"}, \"name\": \"Reset\", \"id\": \"cf23d1c8-c65e-41c0-8d25-e6f56513e8e7\"}, {\"task_class\": \"ajenti.plugins.tasks.tasks.CommandTask\", \"params\": {\"command\": \"curl -I http://toldot.ru/?ty_cache=1\"}, \"name\": \"Toldot cache\", \"id\": \"e75e5903-be69-47a1-9464-1f383f5fe806\"}, {\"task_class\": \"ajenti.plugins.tasks.tasks.CommandTask\", \"params\": {\"command\": \"./reset.sh\"}, \"name\": \"Reset_Sites\", \"id\": \"6b31e811-fff4-45a2-9617-38363e7fbc6c\"}]}"
            }, 
            "password": "sha512|$6$rounds=40000$oyrtyJ5RQVSS6Bwr$hxOZRozeRU7Ux.r7Er2EIFpD3Ka33k7bXjaw3CxKWWvkEmlUyJffPkdt4g6Mqng0D1HDsRXNajuAdCOhiQSaF1", 
            "permissions": []
        }
    }, 
    "language": "ru_RU", 
    "bind": {
        "host": "0.0.0.0", 
        "port": 8055
    }, 
    "enable_feedback": true, 
    "ssl": {
        "enable": true, 
        "certificate_path": "/etc/ajenti/ajenti.pem"
    }, 
    "authentication": true, 
    "installation_id": 62040
}
```

I need the catch or try. If the port 8055 is busy, then use the port 8056. How to do this?

My server has a several web-sites. When I reset them, Ajenti not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajenti is a little slow releasing the used port.

Kill the port, its probably still in use with  ***fuser -k 8055/tcp*** command

fuser 8055/tcp to check whats happening

Patcher